# Robotframework Imported jar library 'SwingLibrary' contains no keywords

Tags: jython, robotframework

I am trying to include SwingLibrary to my robot framework tests. I have downloaded the whole jar with dependencies and added the environment variable **JYTHONPATH** with the value **C:\TMP\JYTHONPATH\SwingLibrary-1.9.6.jar;**. I am using :

```
Robot Framework 3.0.2 (Jython 2.7.0 on java1.7.0_79)
```

My robot test is pretty simple:

```
*** Settings ***
Library       OperatingSystem
Library       SwingLibrary

*** Variables ***
${MESSAGE}    Hello, world!

*** Test Cases ***
My Test
  [Documentation]    Example test
  Log    ${MESSAGE}
  My Keyword    /WA

Another Test
  Should Be Equal    ${MESSAGE}    Hello, world!

*** Keywords ***
My Keyword
  [Arguments]    ${path}
  Directory Should Exist    ${path}
```

I run the script using:

```
jython -vv -m robot -L TRACE -d out tests.robot
```

It then complains that

```
Imported library 'SwingLibrary' contains no keywords.
```

As I ran jython with verbose output I have the following output about SwingLibrary:

```
import: trying source D:\WA\Z-TMP\test\SwingLibrary
import: trying precompiled with no source D:\WA\Z-TMP\test\SwingLibrary$py.class
import: trying source C:\TMP\JYTHONPATH\SwingLibrary-1.9.6.jar\SwingLibrary
import: trying precompiled with no source C:\TMP\JYTHONPATH\SwingLibrary-1.9.6.jar\SwingLibrary$py.class
import: trying source C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\SwingLibrary
import: trying precompiled with no source C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\SwingLibrary$py.class
import: trying SwingLibrary in packagemanager for path None
import: trying SwingLibrary as java class in SysPathJavaLoader
import: 'SwingLibrary' as java class
import: 'SwingLibrary' as java package
[ WARN ] Imported library 'SwingLibrary' contains no keywords.
```

Comment: Did you add C:\TMP\JYTHONPATH\SwingLibrary-1.9.6.jar to CLASSPATH?